# How to SUM two columns in a SELECT query in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

So my question is how to `SUM` two columns in a `SELECT` query in MySQL.Here is the code I have written:

```
$qry = "SELECT supplier,
               SUM(pay) as paid, 
               SUM(remaining) as remain 
        FROM managment 
        WHERE supplier = '".$_GET['ssupplier']."'";
```

But it only plus the column named remaining but not the pay columns.I have 2 pay columns with two values (10 and 50) but after SUM the column I am getting 1050 instead 60.Kindly take a look and help me with this problem.I want this in one table, not two tables
Thanks

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com better learn about SQL injection before you dive deeper into that problem. Right now your whole databoase could be deleted in some seconds.

Comment: I am working on a localhost

Comment: => Try this query i think it's useful.....

    $qry = "SELECT 
       SUM(pay) as 'paid',
       SUM(remaining) as 'remain ',
      (SUM(paid) + SUM(remain )) as 'Total'
    FROM managment WHERE supplier = '".$_GET['ssupplier']."'";

Comment: Yeh, and then the day comes where u go productive with your code without having fixed it.

Comment: _I am getting 1050_ Are these columns defined as numeric or TEXT. I think TEXT if this is happening

Comment: @RiggsFolly these are numeric